# NoSuchMethodError using Google Places on Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, nosuchmethoderror

I'm getting the following error when trying to use Google Place.
 The error happens when I click a location to save it down to my form.
 This works fine in development, but blows up in production.

I've tried changing the linker options with no luck.. 
The only thing I can see that is different between debug and release is "Use Shared Runtime" in debug.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method 
"Lcom/google/android/gms/location/places/internal/PlaceImpl;.getAddress()Ljava/lang/CharSequence;" 
at md5766b115d8f31a35b9917a8faa84b36a4.ExpenseActivity.n_onActivityResult(Native Method)
at md5766b115d8f31a35b9917a8faa84b36a4.ExpenseActivity.onActivityResult(ExpenseActivity.java:56)
```

Comment: What version of Google Play Services is being used? Which Device does it happen on? Which API Level running on the device?

Comment: Based on the `L` character in the error(Indicates Lollipop IIRC), it might seem to me that you are not setting your `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` to 21+. (You should set it to the latest as a rule of thumb). But I would double check with what @SushiHangover has already mentioned.